# Google Apps Scripts - Looping Dates

Tags: google-apps-script

In my google sheets I have three cells:

```yaml
A1 => with the Year ex: 2018
A2 => with the Month ex: 08
A3 => with the number of total months to loop ex: 12
```

My goal is to save in the same sheet the 12 sequential dates with End of Month, ex:

```yaml
31.08.2018 // 30.09.2018 // etc.
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Formula:**

```
=ArrayFormula(EOMONTH(A1&"/"&A2,SEQUENCE(A3,1,0,1)))
```

---

**Google Apps Script:**

```js
//const [y, m, c] = sheet.getRange('A1:A3').getValues().flat();
const y = 2018;
const m = 08;
const c = 12;

const values = [...Array(c).keys()].map(n=>[new Date(y, m + n, 0)]);
console.log(values);
// sheet.getRange(4, 8, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
```

Comment: Tks!
How to save it back to the sheet cell H4?

Comment: Updated. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

Try in B1 :

```
=arrayformula(if(row(A1:A)<=$A$3,EOMONTH(date(A1,A2+row(A1:A),0),0),))
```